# superposition issue caused by mousemove

Tags: javascript, mousemove

my team is developing a timeline application, similar to that in adobe premier pro. The code is about 250 lines long, I met a weird bug I spending all day but failed to solve. Here's the architecture in brief:

- `Stamp` are blocks in a single timeline.
- `Channel` one channel correspond to one reference to timing.
- `Timeline` contains many channels.

I want to achieve `left-right-drag` to change duration on `Stamp` which:

- **drag on left** will change the time of start
- **drag on end** will change the time of end

Therefore, I divided a `Stamp` element into three parts: left handle, main (middle) element and right handle, they are contained in `el`

It is not robust to implement `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` on `left_handle` and `right_handle`, since once the cursor flew out the element during mouse move, `mouseup` will not fire. therefore, **mousemove and mouseup event listeners are set on window**

Please have a look at the code:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/MessizQin/pen/ZEeVxPz)

```js
function render_element(styles, el) {
  for (const [kk, vv] of Object.entries(styles)) {
el.style[kk] = vv;
  }
}

const endListeners = {
'mousemove': [],
'mouseup': [],
};

function addMouseMove(func){
endListeners['mousemove'].push(func);
}

function addMouseUp(func){
endListeners['mouseup'].push(func);
}

class Stamp{
constructor(
    host,
    parent_el,
    width_percent,
){
    this.host = host;
    this.parent_el = parent_el;
    // percent to pixels
    this.width = width_percent / 100 * window.innerWidth;
    [
        this.el,
        this.left_handle,
        this.main_el,
        this.right_handle,
    ] = Array.from({length: 4}, ()=>document.createElement('div'));
    render_element({
        position: 'relative',
        display: 'inline-block',
        width: this.width.toString() + 'px',
        height: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        border: '1px solid',
    }, this.el);
    render_element({
        width: '10%',
        height: '100%',
        border: '1px solid',
    }, this.left_handle);
    render_element({
        width: '80%',
        height: '100%',
        cursor: 'ew-resize',
        border: '1px solid',
    }, this.main_el);
    render_element({
        width: '10%',
        height: '100%',
        cursor: 'ew-resize',
        border: '1px solid',
    }, this.right_handle);
    this.el.appendChild(this.left_handle);
    this.el.appendChild(this.main_el);
    this.el.appendChild(this.right_handle);
    // indicator during movement
    this.indicator = document.createElement('div');
    render_element({
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '5px',
        height: '100%',
        background: 'grey',
        display: 'none',
    }, this.indicator);
    this.el.appendChild(this.indicator);
    // move
    // mousedown start move
    this.in_move = false;
    this.in_left_move = false;
    this.left_handle.addEventListener('mousedown', e=>{
        this.startMove(e);
        this.in_move = true;
        this.in_left_move = true;
    });
    this.right_handle.addEventListener('mousedown', e=>{
        this.startMove(e);
        this.in_move = true;
        this.in_left_move = false;
    });
    // mousemove 
    this.move = function(e){
        if(!this.in_move)return;
        this.moveIndicator(e);
        if(this.in_left_move){
            this.expandLeft(e);
        }else{
            this.expandRight(e);
        }
    }.bind(this);
    addMouseMove(this.move);
    // mouseend finish move
    addMouseUp(function(e){
        this.move(e);
        this.endMove(e);
        this.in_move = false;
    }.bind(this));
    this.parent_el.appendChild(this.el);
    this.getHandleRects = this.getHandleRects.bind(this);
    this.startMove = this.startMove.bind(this);
    this.endMove = this.endMove.bind(this);
    this.expandLeft = this.expandLeft.bind(this);
    this.expandRight = this.expandRight.bind(this);
    this.moveIndicator = this.moveIndicator.bind(this);
}

getHandleRects(){
    return [
        this.el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        this.left_handle.getBoundingClientRect(),
        this.right_handle.getBoundingClientRect(),
    ]
}

startMove(e){
    // show indicator
    this.indicator.style.display = 'block';
    this.moveIndicator(e);
    // change color
    this.el.style.background = 'lightblue';
}

endMove(){
    // hide indicator
    this.indicator.style.display = 'none';
    // change color back
    this.el.style.background = 'none';
}

expandLeft(e){
    var [el_rect, left_rect, right_rect] = this.getHandleRects();
    if(e.clientX >= right_rect.left)return;
    let dif = el_rect.left - e.clientX;
    this.el.style.width = (el_rect.width + dif).toString() + 'px';
    this.el.style.marginLeft = (el_rect.left - dif).toString() + 'px';
}

expandRight(e){
    var [el_rect, left_rect, right_rect] = this.getHandleRects();
    if(e.clientX <= left_rect.right)return;
    this.el.style.width = (e.clientX - el_rect.left).toString() + 'px';
}

moveIndicator(e){
    this.indicator.style.marginLeft = e.clientX.toString() + 'px';
}
}

class Channel{
constructor(
    host,
    parent_el,
    height_percent,
){
    this.host = host;
    this.parent_el = parent_el;
    this.height = height_percent;
    this.stamps = [];
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    render_element({
        position: 'relative',
        width: '100%',
        height: this.height.toString() + '%',
        // display: 'flex',
        // flexDirection: 'row',
        border: '1px solid',
    }, this.el);
    this.stamp_indicator = document.createElement('div');
    this.parent_el.appendChild(this.el);
    this.addStamp = this.addStamp.bind(this);
}

addStamp(width_percent){
    this.stamps.push(new Stamp(this, this.el, width_percent));
    return this.stamps[this.stamps.length - 1];
}
}

class Timeline{
constructor(
    parent_el,
    frame_rate,
){
    this.parent_el = parent_el;
    this.frame_rate = frame_rate;
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    render_element({
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        background: 'lightgrey',
    }, this.el);
    this.channels = [];
    this.parent_el.appendChild(this.el);
    this.el.droppable = true;
    this.el.addEventListener('dragover', e=>{
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    this.el.addEventListener('drop', e=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
    });
    this.addChanel = this.addChannel.bind(this);
}

addChannel(height_percent){
    this.channels.push(new Channel(this, this.el, height_percent));
    return this.channels[this.channels.length - 1];
}
}

var tl = new Timeline(
document.querySelector('#timeline'), 
2,
);
var c1 = tl.addChannel(33);
var s1 = c1.addStamp(20);
// if I call it explicitly, it works fine
s1.expandLeft({
clientX: 50,
});


// endListeners exec at end
for (const [kk, vv] of Object.entries(endListeners)) {
window.addEventListener(kk, e=>{vv.forEach(v=>v(e))});
}
```

```css
#timeline{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

please pay attention to line 138~144, `expandLeft` takes an event as param and changes the `Stamp` position in the `Channel` (which set start time), by changing two css properties:

- margin-left
- width

it is extremely weird that:

- when drag on the right handle, it works exactly as what I expected.
- when calling `expandLeft`, it works fine as well. (this is tested at the end of the script)
- but when I attach it to `mousemove` listener, the width seems to be accumulated.

---

sorry if the question has confused you.
I will be so glad if you can give me a hand.

---

#### Update

I did not see any issue in my calculation, even after I drew many graphs to make sure.

I observed an interesting phenomenon:

- when dragging on the left handle at a fast speed, the width did not change much.
- when dragging on the left handle at a slow speed, the width expand at an increasing rate.
- which despite of mousemove distance, the width always expand at a constant rate that is proportional to time.

Is that due to precision loss or I ignored something in calculation?

---

after I added this test code:

```js
s1.expandRight({
    clientX: 800,
});
setTimeout(()=>{
    s1.expandLeft({
        clientX: 200,
    });
    setTimeout(()=>{
        s1.expandLeft({
            clientX: 400,
        });
        setTimeout(()=>{
            s1.expandLeft({
                clientX: 600,
            });
            }, 500);
    }, 500);
}, 500);
```

I can see that the width is expanding on the right. there must be a calculation I misunderstood or ignored.

---

Now I am totally confused, I assign `getBoundingClientRect().width` to the css width property, this should not change the width, because I assigned the width to itself! but the width keep increasing!!

```js
    expandLeft(e){
        var [el_rect, left_rect, right_rect] = this.getHandleRects();
        if(e.clientX >= right_rect.left)return;
        let dif = el_rect.left - e.clientX;
        // this.el.style.width = (el_rect.width + dif).toString() + 'px';
        this.el.style.width = (el_rect.width).toString() + 'px';
        this.el.style.marginLeft = e.clientX.toString() + 'px';
    }
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/MessizQin/pen/xxqMgRo)

both line gives same result which the width will expand when left handle is being dragged:

- `this.el.style.width = (el_rect.width).toString() + 'px'`
- `this.el.style.width = (this.el.offsetWidth).toString() + 'px';`

I will be so glad if you can explain why this happens

Comment: Do you call all this code on every mouse move? then this will be an overkill for the client I guess

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff yes performance did concern me, but it worked smoothly in test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I succeeded!! by storing the margin left and width before mouse move, and refer to it instead of dynamic margin left and width.

```js
function render_element(styles, el) {
  for (const [kk, vv] of Object.entries(styles)) {
    el.style[kk] = vv;
  }
}

const endListeners = {
    'mousemove': [],
    'mouseup': [],
};

function addMouseMove(func){
    endListeners['mousemove'].push(func);
}

function addMouseUp(func){
    endListeners['mouseup'].push(func);
}

class Stamp{
    constructor(
        host,
        parent_el,
        width_percent,
    ){
        this.host = host;
        this.parent_el = parent_el;
        // percent to pixels
        this.width = width_percent / 100 * window.innerWidth;
        [
            this.el,
            this.left_handle,
            this.main_el,
            this.right_handle,
        ] = Array.from({length: 4}, ()=>document.createElement('div'));
        render_element({
            position: 'relative',
            display: 'inline-block',
            width: this.width.toString() + 'px',
            height: '100%',
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            border: '1px solid',
        }, this.el);
        render_element({
            width: '10%',
            height: '100%',
            border: '1px solid',
        }, this.left_handle);
        render_element({
            width: '80%',
            height: '100%',
            cursor: 'ew-resize',
            border: '1px solid',
        }, this.main_el);
        render_element({
            width: '10%',
            height: '100%',
            cursor: 'ew-resize',
            border: '1px solid',
        }, this.right_handle);
        this.el.appendChild(this.left_handle);
        this.el.appendChild(this.main_el);
        this.el.appendChild(this.right_handle);
        // move
        // mousedown start move
        this.in_move = false;
        this.in_left_move = false;
        this.lwd = this.el.offsetWidth;
        this.lft = this.el.offsetLeft;
        this.left_handle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
            this.startMove(e);
            this.in_move = true;
            this.in_left_move = true;
            this.lwd = this.el.offsetWidth;
            this.lft = this.el.offsetLeft;
        }.bind(this));
        this.right_handle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
            this.startMove(e);
            this.in_move = true;
            this.in_left_move = false;
        }.bind(this));
        // mousemove 
        this.move = function(e){
            if(!this.in_move)return;
            if(this.in_left_move){
                this.expandLeft(e);
            }else{
                this.expandRight(e);
            }
        }.bind(this);
        addMouseMove(this.move);
        // mouseend finish move
        addMouseUp(function(e){
            this.move(e);
            this.endMove(e);
            this.in_move = false;
        }.bind(this));
        this.parent_el.appendChild(this.el);
        this.getHandleRects = this.getHandleRects.bind(this);
        this.startMove = this.startMove.bind(this);
        this.endMove = this.endMove.bind(this);
        this.expandLeft = this.expandLeft.bind(this);
        this.expandRight = this.expandRight.bind(this);
    }

    getHandleRects(){
        return [
            this.el.getBoundingClientRect(),
            this.left_handle.getBoundingClientRect(),
            this.right_handle.getBoundingClientRect(),
        ]
    }

    startMove(e){
        // change color
        this.el.style.background = 'lightblue';
    }

    endMove(){
        // change color back
        this.el.style.background = 'none';
    }

    expandLeft(e){
        var [el_rect, left_rect, right_rect] = this.getHandleRects();
        if(e.clientX >= right_rect.left)return;
        let dif = this.lft - e.clientX;
        this.el.style.width = (this.lwd + dif).toString() + 'px';
        this.el.style.marginLeft = e.clientX.toString() + 'px';
    }

    expandRight(e){
        var [el_rect, left_rect, right_rect] = this.getHandleRects();
        if(e.clientX <= left_rect.right)return;
        this.el.style.width = (e.clientX - el_rect.left).toString() + 'px';
    }
}

class Channel{
    constructor(
        host,
        parent_el,
        height_percent,
    ){
        this.host = host;
        this.parent_el = parent_el;
        this.height = height_percent;
        this.stamps = [];
        this.el = document.createElement('div');
        render_element({
            position: 'relative',
            width: '100%',
            height: this.height.toString() + '%',
            // display: 'flex',
            // flexDirection: 'row',
            border: '1px solid',
        }, this.el);
        this.parent_el.appendChild(this.el);
        this.addStamp = this.addStamp.bind(this);
    }

    addStamp(width_percent){
        this.stamps.push(new Stamp(this, this.el, width_percent));
        return this.stamps[this.stamps.length - 1];
    }
}

class Timeline{
    constructor(
        parent_el,
        frame_rate,
    ){
        this.parent_el = parent_el;
        this.frame_rate = frame_rate;
        this.el = document.createElement('div');
        render_element({
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            background: 'lightgrey',
        }, this.el);
        this.channels = [];
        this.parent_el.appendChild(this.el);
        this.el.droppable = true;
        this.el.addEventListener('dragover', e=>{
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        this.el.addEventListener('drop', e=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
        });
        this.addChanel = this.addChannel.bind(this);
    }

    addChannel(height_percent){
        this.channels.push(new Channel(this, this.el, height_percent));
        return this.channels[this.channels.length - 1];
    }
}

var tl = new Timeline(
    document.querySelector('#timeline'), 
    2,
);
var c1 = tl.addChannel(33);
var s1 = c1.addStamp(20);
var c2 = tl.addChannel(33);
var s2 = c2.addStamp(30);
```

```css
#timeline{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for the offset when expanding left:
`this.el.style.width = (el_rect.width + dif).toString() + 'px';`
vs
`this.el.style.width = (el_rect.width + dif - el_rect.offsetLeft).toString() + 'px';`

```js
function render_element(styles, el) {
  for (const [kk, vv] of Object.entries(styles)) {
el.style[kk] = vv;
  }
}

const endListeners = {
'mousemove': [],
'mouseup': [],
};

function addMouseMove(func){
endListeners['mousemove'].push(func);
}

function addMouseUp(func){
endListeners['mouseup'].push(func);
}

class Stamp{
constructor(
    host,
    parent_el,
    width_percent,
){
    this.host = host;
    this.parent_el = parent_el;
    // percent to pixels
    this.width = width_percent / 100 * window.innerWidth;
    [
        this.el,
        this.left_handle,
        this.main_el,
        this.right_handle,
    ] = Array.from({length: 4}, ()=>document.createElement('div'));
    render_element({
        position: 'relative',
        display: 'inline-block',
        width: this.width.toString() + 'px',
        height: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        border: '1px solid',
    }, this.el);
    render_element({
        width: '10%',
        height: '100%',
        border: '1px solid',
    }, this.left_handle);
    render_element({
        width: '80%',
        height: '100%',
        cursor: 'ew-resize',
        border: '1px solid',
    }, this.main_el);
    render_element({
        width: '10%',
        height: '100%',
        cursor: 'ew-resize',
        border: '1px solid',
    }, this.right_handle);
    this.el.appendChild(this.left_handle);
    this.el.appendChild(this.main_el);
    this.el.appendChild(this.right_handle);
    // indicator during movement
    this.indicator = document.createElement('div');
    render_element({
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '5px',
        height: '100%',
        background: 'grey',
        display: 'none',
    }, this.indicator);
    this.el.appendChild(this.indicator);
    // move
    // mousedown start move
    this.in_move = false;
    this.in_left_move = false;
    this.left_handle.addEventListener('mousedown', e=>{
        this.startMove(e);
        this.in_move = true;
        this.in_left_move = true;
    });
    this.right_handle.addEventListener('mousedown', e=>{
        this.startMove(e);
        this.in_move = true;
        this.in_left_move = false;
    });
    // mousemove 
    this.move = function(e){
        if(!this.in_move)return;
        this.moveIndicator(e);
        if(this.in_left_move){
            this.expandLeft(e);
        }else{
            this.expandRight(e);
        }
    }.bind(this);
    addMouseMove(this.move);
    // mouseend finish move
    addMouseUp(function(e){
        this.move(e);
        this.endMove(e);
        this.in_move = false;
    }.bind(this));
    this.parent_el.appendChild(this.el);
    this.getHandleRects = this.getHandleRects.bind(this);
    this.startMove = this.startMove.bind(this);
    this.endMove = this.endMove.bind(this);
    this.expandLeft = this.expandLeft.bind(this);
    this.expandRight = this.expandRight.bind(this);
    this.moveIndicator = this.moveIndicator.bind(this);
}

getHandleRects(){
    return [
        this.el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        this.left_handle.getBoundingClientRect(),
        this.right_handle.getBoundingClientRect(),
    ]
}

startMove(e){
    // show indicator
    this.indicator.style.display = 'block';
    this.moveIndicator(e);
    // change color
    this.el.style.background = 'lightblue';
}

endMove(){
    // hide indicator
    this.indicator.style.display = 'none';
    // change color back
    this.el.style.background = 'none';
}

expandLeft(e){
    var [el_rect, left_rect, right_rect] = this.getHandleRects();
    if(e.clientX >= right_rect.left)return;
    let dif = el_rect.left - e.clientX;
    this.el.style.width = (el_rect.width + dif - el_rect.offsetLeft).toString() + 'px';
    this.el.style.marginLeft = (el_rect.left - dif).toString() + 'px';
}

expandRight(e){
    var [el_rect, left_rect, right_rect] = this.getHandleRects();
    if(e.clientX <= left_rect.right)return;
    this.el.style.width = (e.clientX - el_rect.left).toString() + 'px';
}

moveIndicator(e){
    this.indicator.style.marginLeft = e.clientX.toString() + 'px';
}
}

class Channel{
constructor(
    host,
    parent_el,
    height_percent,
){
    this.host = host;
    this.parent_el = parent_el;
    this.height = height_percent;
    this.stamps = [];
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    render_element({
        position: 'relative',
        width: '100%',
        height: this.height.toString() + '%',
        // display: 'flex',
        // flexDirection: 'row',
        border: '1px solid',
    }, this.el);
    this.stamp_indicator = document.createElement('div');
    this.parent_el.appendChild(this.el);
    this.addStamp = this.addStamp.bind(this);
}

addStamp(width_percent){
    this.stamps.push(new Stamp(this, this.el, width_percent));
    return this.stamps[this.stamps.length - 1];
}
}

class Timeline{
constructor(
    parent_el,
    frame_rate,
){
    this.parent_el = parent_el;
    this.frame_rate = frame_rate;
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    render_element({
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        background: 'lightgrey',
    }, this.el);
    this.channels = [];
    this.parent_el.appendChild(this.el);
    this.el.droppable = true;
    this.el.addEventListener('dragover', e=>{
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    this.el.addEventListener('drop', e=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
    });
    this.addChanel = this.addChannel.bind(this);
}

addChannel(height_percent){
    this.channels.push(new Channel(this, this.el, height_percent));
    return this.channels[this.channels.length - 1];
}
}

var tl = new Timeline(
document.querySelector('#timeline'), 
2,
);
var c1 = tl.addChannel(33);
var s1 = c1.addStamp(20);
// if I call it explicitly, it works fine
s1.expandLeft({
clientX: 50,
});


// endListeners exec at end
for (const [kk, vv] of Object.entries(endListeners)) {
window.addEventListener(kk, e=>{vv.forEach(v=>v(e))});
}
```

```css
#timeline{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for you help. however, `el_rect.offsetLeft` returns null and width is not modified. even when I changed it to `self.el.offsetLeft` the width did not behave properly. I really hoped that the right side of the element is fixed, and the left side moves as I drag the left handle